# How to merge using Common ID/Column/Primary Key

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge the two tables using common ID

Here is my first table which is subset

```
Category_table1 <- subset(Category_table, select = c(ID,category))
```

[image: Category_table1]

My second table named - final_table_down
which I have **transposed** itself

```
final_table_down <- t(final_table_down)
```

[image]

I tried to using "merge"

```
new_final_table_down <- merge(y = Category_table1 , x = final_table_down, by = "ID", all.y = TRUE )
```

It shows the error as -
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Even I am using by = "ID" condition.

It **works before transposing** the final_table_down but all **NA** values are displayed in the column.

Please guide me why it happens and how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit1 - I am providing info based on randomly generated index values in dput

```
    final_table_down <-
  structure(
    list(
      X12 = c(" 2", " 1", "ebv-miR-BART14", " 2", " 4",
              " 3", " 1", " 0", " 1", " 1"),
      X32 = c(" 6", " 5", "ebv-miR-BART6-5p",
              " 5", " 5", " 6", " 5", " 5", " 5", " 4"),
      X58 = c("12", "10",
              "hsa-let-7b", "12", "13", "13", "11", "11", "12", "11"),
      X59 = c("10",
              " 7", "hsa-let-7c", "10", "11", "10", " 7", " 7", " 9", " 8"),
      X66 = c(" 9", " 8", "hsa-miR-100", " 9", "10", "11", " 7",
              " 9", " 9", " 6"),
      X73 = c(" 6", " 7", "hsa-miR-10a", " 8",
              " 8", " 8", " 6", " 6", " 7", " 6"),
      X74 = c(" 5", " 4",
              "hsa-miR-10b", " 7", " 7", " 8", " 4", " 5", " 5", " 5"),
      X90 = c(" 5", " 4", "hsa-miR-1225-3p", " 5", " 4", " 5",
              " 3", " 3", " 4", " 4"),
      X108 = c(" 4", " 2", "hsa-miR-1254",
               " 3", " 4", " 4", " 3", " 4", " 3", " 1"),
      X116 = c("13",
               " 8", "hsa-miR-125b", "13", "13", "14", " 9", "10", "11",
               " 8"),
      X125 = c(" 1", " 2", "hsa-miR-127-3p", " 6", " 5",
               " 4", " 3", " 2", " 4", " 3"),
      X137 = c(" 6", " 4", "hsa-miR-1280",
               " 5", " 6", " 5", " 5", " 5", " 6", " 5"),
      X185 = c(" 8",
               " 6", "hsa-miR-143", " 9", "10", "10", " 7", "10", "10",
               " 7"),
      X187 = c("11", " 6", "hsa-miR-145", "10", "12", "12",
               " 6", " 9", "10", " 7"),
      X206 = c(" 4", " 5", "hsa-miR-154",
               " 7", " 5", " 5", " 5", " 4", " 5", " 4"),
      X237 = c(
        " 8",
        " 7",
        "hsa-miR-193a-3p (+++ See note below)",
        " 8",
        " 8",
        " 8",
        " 7",
        " 8",
        " 7",
        " 7"
      ),
      X238 = c(" 1", " 4", "hsa-miR-193a-5p",
               " 4", " 5", " 6", " 4", " 3", " 4", " 4"),
      X241 = c(" 7",
               " 6", "hsa-miR-195", " 8", " 8", " 9", " 7", " 6", " 7",
               " 6"),
      X255 = c(" 7", " 5", "hsa-miR-199b-5p", " 9", " 9",
               " 8", " 7", " 5", " 8", " 5"),
      X263 = c(" 3", " 2", "hsa-miR-204",
               " 4", " 5", " 5", " 3", " 4", " 4", " 3"),
      X264 = c("13",
               "10", "hsa-miR-205", " 3", "12", "14", " 4", " 7", " 8",
               "10"),
      X284 = c(" 7", " 6", "hsa-miR-216a", " 7", " 8", " 6",
               " 6", " 6", " 6", " 6"),
      X312 = c(" 5", " 2", "hsa-miR-296-5p",
               " 5", " 6", " 6", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4"),
      X316 = c(" 2",
               " 2", "hsa-miR-299-5p", " 5", " 1", " 3", " 2", " 1", " 3",
               " 3"),
      X320 = c(" 5", " 4", "hsa-miR-300", " 5", " 4", " 5",
               " 4", " 5", " 4", " 4"),
      X340 = c(" 5", " 3", "hsa-miR-323-3p",
               " 4", " 3", " 4", " 3", " 4", " 4", " 3"),
      X345 = c(" 5",
               " 5", "hsa-miR-328", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 3",
               " 3"),
      X351 = c(" 4", " 5", "hsa-miR-335", " 7", " 6", " 6",
               " 5", " 2", " 4", " 4"),
      X352 = c(" 2", " 4", "hsa-miR-337-3p",
               " 6", " 4", " 5", " 4", " 4", " 5", " 3"),
      X366 = c(" 4",
               " 3", "hsa-miR-34c-3p", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 3", " 4", " 4",
               " 3"),
      X378 = c(" 5", " 3", "hsa-miR-371-3p", " 4", " 4",
               " 5", " 4", " 4", " 4", " 3"),
      X387 = c(" 5", " 5", "hsa-miR-376c",
               " 8", " 7", " 5", " 6", " 5", " 6", " 5"),
      X408 = c(" 3",
               " 3", "hsa-miR-432", " 5", " 3", " 2", " 3", " 2", " 3",
               " 2"),
      X417 = c(" 7", " 9", "hsa-miR-451", "12", "11", "13",
               " 6", " 8", " 9", " 8"),
      X430 = c(" 3", " 1", "hsa-miR-487b",
               " 5", " 3", " 3", " 1", " 3", " 3", " 2"),
      X440 = c(" 6",
               " 6", "hsa-miR-495", " 6", " 6", " 6", " 6", " 5", " 6",
               " 5"),
      X442 = c(" 7", " 6", "hsa-miR-497", " 8", " 9", " 9",
               " 7", " 6", " 7", " 6"),
      X487 = c(" 4", " 4", "hsa-miR-520d-3p",
               " 3", " 4", " 3", " 3", " 4", " 4", " 3"),
      X489 = c(" 3",
               " 5", "hsa-miR-520e", " 6", " 6", " 7", " 5", " 5", " 5",
               " 6"),
      X504 = c("10", " 7", "hsa-miR-542-3p", " 9", " 9",
               " 7", " 8", "10", "10", "10"),
      X518 = c(" 8", " 6", "hsa-miR-548g",
               " 5", " 8", " 7", " 5", " 4", " 5", " 6"),
      X542 = c(" 8",
               " 7", "hsa-miR-563", " 8", " 8", " 8", " 7", " 7", " 7",
               " 7"),
      X552 = c(" 5", " 5", "hsa-miR-574-3p", " 6", " 7",
               " 5", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 5"),
      X558 = c(
        "11",
        " 9",
        "hsa-miR-579 (+++ See note below)",
        "11",
        "11",
        " 8",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
        "11"
      ),
      X572 = c(" 3",
               " 4", "hsa-miR-592", " 4", " 7", " 6", " 4", " 4", " 5",
               " 5"),
      X595 = c(" 7", " 5", "hsa-miR-615-5p", " 6", " 7",
               " 6", " 6", " 6", " 7", " 6"),
      X598 = c(" 5", " 3", "hsa-miR-619",
               " 3", " 4", " 4", " 3", " 3", " 3", " 4"),
      X599 = c(" 4",
               " 3", "hsa-miR-620", " 4", " 4", " 2", " 3", " 3", " 2",
               " 4"),
      X632 = c(" 3", " 2", "hsa-miR-654-3p", " 4", " 4",
               " 4", " 5", " 4", " 3", " 3"),
      X634 = c(" 7", " 6", "hsa-miR-655",
               " 7", " 6", " 6", " 6", " 7", " 6", " 6"),
      X709 = c("11",
               " 7", "hsa-miR-99a", "11", "12", "12", " 8", " 8", " 9",
               " 7"),
      X729 = c(" 5", " 4", "kshv-miR-K12-4-5p", " 4", " 4",
               " 3", " 3", " 4", " 4", " 3")
    ),
    row.names = c(
      "GSM1029168",
      "GSM1029333",
      "ID",
      "GSM1029187",
      "GSM1029197",
      "GSM1029160",
      "GSM1029224",
      "GSM1029301",
      "GSM1029299",
      "GSM1029306"
    ),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

For Category_table1

```
Category_table1 <-  structure(
  list(
    ID = c(
      "GSM1029105",
      "GSM1029334",
      "GSM1029263",
      "GSM1029286",
      "GSM1029316",
      "GSM1029166",
      "GSM1029091",
      "GSM1029322",
      "GSM1029198",
      "GSM1029153",
      "GSM1029087",
      "GSM1029140",
      "GSM1029325",
      "GSM1029189",
      "GSM1029330",
      "GSM1029150",
      "GSM1029175",
      "GSM1029358",
      "GSM1029221",
      "GSM1029100",
      "GSM1029180",
      "GSM1029201",
      "GSM1029184",
      "GSM1029205",
      "GSM1029347",
      "GSM1029130",
      "GSM1029172",
      "GSM1029218",
      "GSM1029111",
      "GSM1029317",
      "GSM1029264",
      "GSM1029277",
      "GSM1029235",
      "GSM1029314",
      "GSM1029125",
      "GSM1029255",
      "GSM1029212",
      "GSM1029159",
      "GSM1029200",
      "GSM1029293"
    ),
    category = c(
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "1",
      "0",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "1",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(
    19L,
    248L,
    177L,
    200L,
    230L,
    80L,
    5L,
    236L,
    112L,
    67L,
    1L,
    54L,
    239L,
    103L,
    244L,
    64L,
    89L,
    272L,
    135L,
    14L,
    94L,
    115L,
    98L,
    119L,
    261L,
    44L,
    86L,
    132L,
    25L,
    231L,
    178L,
    191L,
    149L,
    228L,
    39L,
    169L,
    126L,
    73L,
    114L,
    207L
  ),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: Please don't share data as images, use ``dput()`` instead.

Comment: Please check I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to work out without an reproducible example. You should consider adding a code for your "tables" (they should be data frames) here so people can help you.

Just by looking at it, I am taking a wild guess that you second "table" `second_table_down` doesn't have an "ID" named column. It look like they are row names.

`second_table_down$ID # to see if this is the problem`